# My website is "Example", but during Google searches, it says my web title is "example.com" - how can I change that?

Tags: seo, google-search, title

I am a new website designer. My website is "Example" but during Google searches it says my web title is `example.com`. How can I change that?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I would start by making it 2 words "Roy Jewelry" - and your tag "Let you more beautiful" is not good English, I think you mean "Let you be more beautiful"